# gradle cannot read correct local maven repository on windows

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I use mavenLocal() to let gradle use local maven repository. I put my settings.xml under ~.m2. The settings.xml looks like below:

```
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
    <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->
  <localRepository>d:/green/maven-repository</localRepository>
```

When running maven command, mvn can find the correct repository. 
 When running gradle command, it still looks for ~/.m2/repository. It looks like gradle cannot read d:/green/maven-repository correctly.

The build.dradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "1.5.2.RELEASE"
        kotlinVersion = "1.1.2"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
    }
}

apply {
    plugin("kotlin")
    plugin("kotlin-spring")
    plugin("kotlin-jpa")
    plugin("org.springframework.boot")
    plugin 'java'
    plugin 'idea'
//    plugin: 'spring-boot'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'mini_springboot'
    version = '0.0.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
//    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.8.4")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

Comment: show your gradle script

Comment: Which version of Gradle is it that you are using?

Comment: I'm asking, because gradle honors this setting since 1.0-milestone-8